# How to use dynamic fragments in android?

Tags: android, dynamic, android-fragments

I have a list of data in left side. I need to show the details in right side by creating new activity depending on the selection in the left side data.

For each and every item in the list in the left side I need to show the details in a separate activity.

How to achieve this?

Comment: see this awesome library https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu

Comment: use a naivgation drawer http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation-drawer.html sample @ http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html

Comment: I need to use this for both phone and tablets.In Tablets i need left and right side view.In phone i need separate views.

Answer (score 2):

What you need is called [Master-Detail-Flow](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_Android_Master/Detail_Flow_Tutorial). There is a template available in Eclipse if you set up your project. The tutorial in the link is explaining it in detail.

[image]

To use it you should have a look at [Fragments](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html).

Comment: Please read the question carefully.I need multiple activities in right side.

Comment: Please have a look in Fragments and the tutorial, which is the proper way to go for your approach.